# Getting around Primary Key requiring non-nullable columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, foreign-key, primary-key, constraint

## Word Problem

I need to be able to create a table that has a column which is a foreign key and is nullable, but is also part of the (composite) primary key. Obviously the problem is that (at least with SQL Server 2014) I cannot have a nullable column in a primary key.

## Example

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    Id1 INT NOT NULL,
    Id2 INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id1, Id2)
)

CREATE TABLE Test2
(
    TestId1 INT NOT NULL,
    TestId2 INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (TestId1, TestId2),
    FOREIGN KEY (TestId1, TestId2) REFERENCES Test (Id1, Id2)
)
```

The error is on the Primary Key of `Test2`:

> A primary key constraint cannot be defined on the nullable column 'TestId2' in the table or user-defined table type ...

My workaround:

```
CREATE TABLE Test3
(
    TestId1 INT NOT NULL,
    TestId2Calc AS COALESCE(TestId2, -1) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    TestId2 INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (TestId1, TestId2Calc),
    FOREIGN KEY (TestId1, TestId2) REFERENCES Test (Id1, Id2)
)
```

But this feels dirty. Is this my only option?

Answer (score 4):

There is no physical difference between Primary Key and a Unique Clustered Index.  So unless you are using some tool that *requires* a Primary Key, you can do

```
CREATE TABLE Test2
(
    TestId1 INT NOT NULL,
    TestId2 INT NULL,
    UNIQUE CLUSTERED (TestId1, TestId2),
    FOREIGN KEY (TestId1, TestId2) REFERENCES Test (Id1, Id2)
)
```

Comment: Can this still be the target of `FOREIGN KEY` references? (Not that it matters, I don't think I can `FOREIGN KEY` reference my current situation.)

Comment: SQL Server allows unique indexes to be the target of an FOREIGN KEY.  But you still wouldn't be able to insert a NULL in Test2.TestId2 because of the constraint referencing Test.  So the model still has issues.

Comment: I was able to insert `NULL` into the `Test2Id` of both your version and mine. (Though I was also able to insert values that are not in `Test`, that's not part of my issue here, I have a second FK to prohibit that.)

Comment: Here's a DBFiddle, `Test2` is your version, `Test3` is my workaround: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=4818089b447f96983975131b6f29b28f